# Finding correct CRC using CRC RevEng

Tags: reverse-engineering, crc, crc16

I have a protocol that I fail to find the correct checksum algorithm for. I stumbled upon a program called CRC RevEng. Unfortunately I fail to detect the correct algorithm (using the command `reveng -sx message1 message2 message3 ... messageN -w 16`). What other approaches would you recommend?

I have some messages encoded in hex below:

```
"90820100303030325A5032303030313165640101373D065328000000057500000230000000000000000000000000002B3F00003FF000000000000000000000000018000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003238313131390090038596"
"90820100303030325A5032303030313165640101373D065428000000057500000230000000000000000000000230002B3F00003FF00000000000000000000000002900000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000323831313139009003044C"
"90820110303030325A5032303030313165640101373D065828000000057500000230000000000000000000000230002B3F00003FF00000000000000000000000000300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000323831313139009003F4E5"
"90820111303030325A5032303030313165640101373D065928000000057500000230000000000000000000000230002B3F00003FF00000000000000000000000000400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000323831313139009003E708"
"90820110303030325A4330313031313165640101373D065928000000057500000230000000000000000000000230002B3F00003FF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003238313131390090037B4F"
"90820111303030325A5032303030313165640101373D070028000000057500000230000000000000000000000230002B3F00003FF00000000000000000000000004800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000323831313139009003B024"
"90820100303030325A4330313031313165640101373D070128000000057500000230000000000000000000000230002B3F00003FF00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000323831313139009003B299"
"90820110303030325A5032303030313165640101373D070228000000057500000230000000000000000000000230002B3F00003FF000000000000000000000000053000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003238313131390090037120"
"90820100303030325A4330313031313165640101373D070128000000057500000230000000000000000000000230002B3F00003FF00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000323831313139009003B299"
"90820111303030325A5032303030313165640101373D070328000000057500000230000000000000000000000230002B3F00003FF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003238313131390090033A51"
"90820110303030325A5032303030313165640101373D070328000000057500000230000000000000000000000230002B3F00003FF00000000000000000000000005500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000323831313139009003402A"
```

Due to a measurement with an oscilloscope, I assume those are just one message each (they the bits arrived without delay in between).

Comment: Try xor'ing pairs of messages to get one with mostly zeroes. The xor will cancel out crc initial value and any post crc complementing. It may also give you an idea if it is a CRC or something else.

Comment: So xor'ing two got me "000000010000000000130201000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002300000000000000000000000000000000000000018000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005707".. I lack the experience to tell, whether this is a CRC or something else.. RevEng gave me "no models found" on this input..?

Comment: I looked which messages gave me the smallest differences by xor'ing and used them to input them into RevEngl.. This now gave me a list of "results".. :) but, when I add too many, I get no results again.. is this a sign of a non-crc?

Comment: As long as you xor even numbers of messages, normally just different pairs of messages, if reverse crc is failing, then it's probably not a crc.